# Auto increment column from number of data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql

I want to make the table automatically increasing its column based on number of data.

this is example of query that i tried,

```
================================
No | Item  | Description
1    AB      Item for AB
2    AC      Item For AC
```

there is 2 row in the result of my query. I want to show it only in 1 row, but the column is increasing.

```
=================================================
No | Item  | Item_2 | Description  | Description_2
1    AB      AC       Item for AB    Item for AC
```

and if there is 3 data, there will be automatically create 'Item_3' and 'Description_3'

I have tried like this

```
SELECT i.Item, d.Description FROM ItemTable i
INNER JOIN DescriptionItem di on di.ItemCode = i.ItemCode
```

Comment: This is bad reporting design.  As your data set grows, the number of rows, not columns, should be growing.

Comment: Yeah, but my teacher ask me to do this. I tried using stuff in 'Item'

Comment: only possibility was by using recursive function we can do this solution

Comment: did you mean using Cursor?

Comment: couple of things.... Depending on your database the implementation could be different so please tag to a specific database (MySQL, Oracle ect).  But a starting point would be to google a pivot query and start from there.